# Find domain of the inequality

Tags: functions

$$
\frac{x}{x-1} \geq \frac{1}{e}
$$

I can see at $x=1$, it is undefined. But when I rearrange the inequality, like below.

$$
ex \geq x-1
$$

Now $x=1$ is not undefined. I am confused and do not know how it is possible and what is going on. Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Your implication is wrong when $x-1 < 0$. And just forget about $x=1$. It does not make any sense.

Comment: Is $e$ here the base of natural logarithms?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. For $$x>1$$ we get $$x\geq \frac{x-1}{e}$$ and for $$x<1$$ we obtain $$x\le \frac{x-1}{e}$$